# Sorting a string character by character

Tags: javascript

My code isn't sorting the characters.

I've read about this and saw a lot of answers. And I found that I could use sort() to sort characteres, however i don't understand why it isn't working.

```
var string = readLine("Which letters do you want to sort?")
               .toLowerCase()
               .split(" ")
               .sort();
print(string);
```

Comment: Does your input have a space between every letter?

Comment: You have to show more code, we've no clue what `readLine` returns.

Comment: You have to `join` the array of characters: `....sort().join("")`. Also, `split` should be `split("")` with an empty string not `split(" ")` with a space

Comment: `.split(" ")` will split on spaces not letters.

Comment: @JinL042 if there are not spaces, split won't split anything. If you want to split characters use `.split('')` (no space)

Comment: Oh, okay thank you very much

Comment: You may be trying to do something like `'Which letters do you want to sort?'.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('')`, which outputs _?acdeehhilnoooorrsstttttuwwy_, but not sure what `readLine()` is supposed to do.

Comment: @benvc OP is probably using nodejs not the browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.split(" ")` splits the string based on every space it has in it. If they're not separated by spaces, you need to split it on an empty string instead, which will separate every character. Replace that line with `.split("")` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

`.split(" ")` will separate your string by words and sort those words, remove the blank space and all characters should be sorted.

```
var string = readLine("Which letters do you want to sort?")
           .toLowerCase() // Omit this line if you wan't to be case sensitive. 
           .split("")
           .sort();
print(string); // [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "?", "a", "c", "d", "e", "e", "h", "h", "i", "l", "n", "o", "o", "o", "o", "r", "r", "s", "s", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "u", "w", "w", "y"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var string= "Which letters do you want to sort?"
             .toLowerCase()
             .split("")
             .sort();
console.log(string);
```